# Error of mexfunction variables in an array of a structure variable

Tags: c, matlab, mex

Recently, I tried to write mexfunctions using structure variables.
I watched the tutorial but got confused because of how the variable values are passed.
The following example (`mexfunction_using_ex_wrong.m & mexfunction_using_ex_wrong.cpp`) demonstrates how to fetch the variables passed from matlab in mexfunction.
However, in this case, the result is:

```
address i_c1=2067094464 i_c2=2067094464
        i_c1=10         i_c2=10
address i_c1=1327990656 i_c2=2067100736
        i_c1=2          i_c2=20
address i_c1=2067101056 i_c2=2067063424
        i_c1=3          i_c2=30
```

As can be seen, the 1st element of the c1 & c2 array of a structure variable is accidentally the same.

But, in another example (`mexfunction_using_ex_correct.m & mexfunction_using_ex_correct.cpp`), the elements of array 1 (b1) and array 2(b2) of a structure variable are unrelated as I expect.
The result is:

```
address i_b1=1978456576 i_b2=1326968576
        i_b1=1          i_b2=10
address i_b1=1978456584 i_b2=1326968584
        i_b1=2          i_b2=20
address i_b1=1978456592 i_b2=1326968592
        i_b1=3          i_b2=30
```

However, it's more common to use the 1st example in programming. so could anybody explain why in the 1st example the addresses of i_c1 & i_c2 are the same?

The following code is mexfunction_using_ex_wrong.m

```
clc
clear all
close all

mex mexfunction_using_ex_c_wrong.cpp;

a.b(1).c1=double(1);
a.b(2).c1=double(2);
a.b(3).c1=double(3);

a.b(1).c2=double(1);
a.b(2).c2=double(2);
a.b(3).c2=double(3);

mexfunction_using_ex_c_wrong(a);
```

The following code is mexfunction_using_ex_c_wrong.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{   
     int i, j, k;

     double *i_c1;
     double *i_c2;

     // for struct variables(pointers) inside fcwcontext
     mxArray *mx_b, *mx_c1, *mx_c2;    

     mx_b=mxGetField(prhs[0], 0, "b");

    for(i = 0;i < 3;i=i+1)
    {               
        mx_c1=mxGetField(mx_b, i, "c1");
        mx_c2=mxGetField(mx_b, i, "c2");

        i_c1=mxGetPr(mx_c1);
        i_c2=mxGetPr(mx_c2);        

        *i_c2=(*i_c2)*10;

        printf("address i_c1=%d i_c2=%d\n", i_c1, i_c2);
        printf(" i_c1=%g i_c2=%g\n", *i_c1, *i_c2);               
    }                  
}
```

The following code is mexfunction_using_ex_c_correct.m

```
clc
clear all
close all

mex mexfunction_using_ex_correct.cpp;

a.b1(1)=double(1);
a.b1(2)=double(2);
a.b1(3)=double(3);

a.b2(1)=double(1);
a.b2(2)=double(2);
a.b2(3)=double(3);

mexfunction_using_ex_correct(a);
```

The following code is mexfunction_using_ex_c_correct.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[]) 
{   
     int i, j, k;

     double *i_b1;
     double *i_b2;

     mxArray *mx_b1, *mx_b2;    

     mx_b1=mxGetField(prhs[0], 0, "b1");
     mx_b2=mxGetField(prhs[0], 0, "b2");

    for(i = 0;i < 3;i=i+1)
    {                       
        i_b1=mxGetPr(mx_b1);
        i_b2=mxGetPr(mx_b2);        

        i_b2[i]=i_b2[i]*10;

        printf("address i_b1=%d i_b2=%d\n", &i_b1[i], &i_b2[i]);
        printf(" i_b1=%g i_b2=%g\n", i_b1[i], i_b2[i]);                
    }                  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The addresses are not "accidentally the same" - they're *intentionally* the same, due to MATLAB's internal copy-on-write optimisations. If you look at the MEX documentation, you'll see warnings scattered around...

> [Do not modify any `prhs` values in your MEX-file. Changing the data in these read-only mxArrays can produce undesired side effects.](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexfunction.html)

...in various forms...

> [**Note**   Inputs to a MEX-file are constant read-only mxArrays. Do not modify the inputs. Using `mxSetCell*` or `mxSetField*` functions to modify the cells or fields of a MATLAB® argument causes unpredictable results.](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetfield.html)

...trying to make it very clear that you should *absolutely not modify anything you recieve as an input*. By calling `mxGetPr()` on input data and writing back to that pointer as you do with `i_b2` and `i_c2`, you're getting right into that "unpredictable results" territory - if you look at `a.b(1).c1` in the MATLAB workspace after the call, it'll really be 10 even though you "only" changed `c2`.

From MEX, you're looking at the raw data storage without any knowledge of, or access to, MATLAB's internal housekeeping, so the only *safe* way to modify anything is to use the `mxCreate*` or `mxDuplicate*` functions to get your own safe arrays you can then do whatever you want with, and pass back to MATLAB via `plhs`.

That said, I will admit to having abused [in-place modification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1708433/3156750) for a significant performance gain in one instance where I could guarantee my data was unique and unshared, but it's at best unsupported and at worst downright perilous.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I finally solve this issue. [The answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/uploaded_files/1487/mxsharedcopy.c) completely solves my problem with a very useful function 
mxCreateSharedDataCopy(). However, this function is a undocumented function which is only possible to be called in Matlab 2014 if the file is .c. If that file is .cpp, linker couldn't find it. The error message is error LNK2019: external symbol unresolved "struct mxArray_tag * __cdecl mxCreateSharedDataCopy(struct mxArray_tag const *)".

Comment: I would really, **strongly** recommend not doing that - Use `mxDuplicateArray`, modify _that_ copy, then pass it back via `plhs`. Learn how to use MEX _properly_ and get comfortable with it before even thinking about dabbling in unsupported hacks and undocumented implementation details. If (as in my case) the hack saves you about an hour and a half of runtime per day during development, then maybe it's worth the risk; For learning, it's a terrible idea.